# Firefox - Choppy Animations & Effects Over Fixed Position Background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've tried for days to figure out what's going wrong here and haven't been able to crack it. I've got two containers. The first has a fixed position background image and is styled like this:

```
#first-window {
    background: url(http://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/img/cinque.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

The second is the same, but with no background:

```
#second-window {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
}
```

Then I've got a hamburger menu which, when clicked, brings up an opaque wrapper, animates to a close-button and pulls the navigation panes out from their positions off-screen.

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/*========================================================================
                           Navigation
===========================================================================*/

    $('a.menu, #fade-wrapper').click(function() {
        var clicked = $(this);
        if (clicked.is(fadeWrapper) || clicked.hasClass('open')) {
            closeMenu();
        } else {
            openMenu();
    });


/*=========================================================================
                       Variables and Functions
===========================================================================*/

    var nav = $('nav'),
        barOne = $('.menu-bar-top'),
        barTwo = $('.menu-bar-bottom'),
        barThree = $('.menu-bar-mid'),
        menuTrigger = $('a.menu'),
        fadeWrapper = $('#fade-wrapper'),
        footerHidden = $('footer.hidden'),
        bar = $('.bar');

    function transformMenu(top, transform) {
        return {
            'top': top,
            'transform': transform,
            '-webkit-transform': transform,
            '-moz-transform': transform,
            '-ms-transform': transform,
            '-o-transform': transform
        };
    }

    function openMenu() {
        fadeWrapper.stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
        menuTrigger.addClass('open');
        $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        nav.stop(true, true).animate({'left': '+=145px'}, 200);
        footerHidden.stop(true, true).animate({'bottom': '+=80px'}, 200);
        barOne.css(transformMenu('18px', 'rotate(405deg)'));
        barTwo.css(transformMenu('18px', 'rotate(-405deg)'));
        barThree.fadeOut(1);
        bar.not(barThree).css('background', '#66e2e3');
        barThree.css('background', '#303030');
    }

    function closeMenu() {
        menuTrigger.removeClass('open');
        $('html, body').css('overflow', '');
        nav.stop(true, true).animate({'left': '-=145px'}, 200);
        footerHidden.stop(true, true).animate({'bottom': '-=80px'}, 200);
        bar.css('background', '');
        barOne.css(transformMenu('13px' , 'rotate(360deg)'));
        barTwo.css(transformMenu('23px', 'rotate(-360deg)'));
        barThree.fadeTo(200, 1);
        fadeWrapper.stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

Believe it or not, I've pared this down significantly for SO. The problem occurs in Firefox when you fire `openMenu()` or `closeMenu()` over the first window. The animation is just choppy, and the screen intermittently flashes white when `#fade-wrapper` fades in or out. The same animation looks nice and smooth over `#second-window`, whose only difference is that it has no background image.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q8GJL/2/

The issue is more subtle there, I imagine because I've left out all but the most fundamental animations. You may have an easier time seeing problem on the live site: http://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com

Ideas?

Comment: I tested the fiddle and the live site in both Chrome and Firefox (my system is Ubuntu 13.10 with an Intel i5 processor) and both perform exactly the same, smoothly. I know on Windows, Firefox is a lot worse than Chrome.  Also try starting Firefox in safe-mode (which disables extensions)

Comment: Huh. I tried it in Safe Mode and saw no difference, either on my own system (Mavericks OSX, core i5) or on a significantly less powerful Windows machine. Really choppy over `#first-window`, perfectly smooth over `#second-window`. Did you try firing the menu trigger several times?

Comment: OK, trying again while clicking the menu button repeatedly really fast. The animation is never choppy over the first-window or second-window, however with first-window I do experience the "white flash", but ONLY when the menu is already open, then quickly close + open it (I mean double click REALLY fast). Sorry I couldn't help more. It looks good overall

Comment: Thanks for checking it out anyway.